# Javascript: prevent internal element "scrolling" in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that has a div with a width larger than its' parent, with the parent being set to `overflow: hidden;`. I have javascript that is setting the `left` positioning of the big div to create "pages". You can click a link to move between pages.

All of that works great, but the problem is if you tab from one "page" element to another, it completely messes up all the left positioning to move between the pages.

You can recreate this bug in the fiddle I set up by setting your focus to one of the input boxes on page ONE and tabbing until it takes you to page two.

**I've set up a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/E7u9X/).**

The code that is important is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="pagesContainer">
        <div class="page" class="active">
            <h2>Page One</h2>
            [... Page 1 Content here...]
        </div>

        <div class="page">
            <h2>Page Two</h2>
            [... Page  Content here...]
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
}

    .pagesContainer {
        position: relative; /*Width set to 10,000 px in js
    }

    .form .page {
        width: 400px;
        float: left;
    }
```

JS:

```
slidePage: function(page, direction, currentPage) {
    if (direction == 'next') {
        var animationDirection = '-=';
        if (page.index() >= this.numPages) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (direction == 'previous') {
        var animationDirection = '+=';
        if (page.index() < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Get page height
    var height = page.height();
    this.heightElement.animate({
        height: height
    }, 600);

    //Clear active page
    this.page.removeClass('active');
    this.page.eq(page.index()).addClass('active');

    //Locate the exact page to skip to
    var slideWidth = page.outerWidth(true) * this.difference(this.currentPage.index(), page.index());

    this.container.animate({
        left: animationDirection + slideWidth
    }, 600);

    this.currentPage = page;
}
```

The primary problem is that whatever happens when you tab from say, an input box on page one to something on page 2, it takes you there, but css still considers you to be at `left: 0px;`. I've been looking all over for a solution but so far all google has revealed to me is how to stop scrollbar scrolling.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

P.S. The html was set up like this so that if javascript is disabled it will still show up all on one page and still function properly.

Comment: have you tried using jQuery to jump to the page the element is on, whenever an element in page 1 gets focus?

Comment: @SamHuckaby I think I could try that, but the problem is when you get tabbed over left positioning isn't changing. is there something in css or javascript that I can use to determine where exactly the user is now in inside the element? $('element').css('left') returns 0. Is there something else?

Comment: I'm trying to think about another way... possibly count how many page div's there are before the one the user is currently focused inside... I'll see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle with a fix for the first tab with the form: http://jsfiddle.net/E7u9X/1/
. Basically, what you can do is to focus on the first "tabbable" element in a tab after the last one gets blurred, like so:

```
$('.form input').last().blur(function(){
    $('.form input').first().focus();
});
```

(This is just an example, the first active element could be any other element)

Comment: thanks for the response! It definitely has gotten me closer to finding a solution than I would have had before. Question: take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/yTq5d/1/. Yours didn't work once I added in inputs on the other pages. However, I was able to achieve the same result with setting `:eq(<page.index()>)`, but i had to do it seperately with every page. The code is at the top in that fiddle. Would you mind helping me make a cleaner solution?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yTq5d/2/ But if your pages are going to be static, maybe it would be better to give a class to first and last elements on each page.

Answer (score 1):

Elements with overflow: hidden still have scrolling, just no scroll bars. This can be useful at times and annoying at others. This is why your position left is at zero, but your view of the element has changed. Set scrollLeft to zero when you change "pages", should do the trick.

Comment: thank you, I did end up using the .scrollLeft() now that I know it exists, but it didn't exactly solve my problem. I used it in combination with pckill's answer.